# jsPDF generate from html, div text to fit PDF page width

Tags: jspdf

I have a really simple page (a `div` that contains text and a simple table, no images, no complex CSS) that I want to convert to PDF using jsPDF.html() function. My only request is that the text lines are adjusted (no zoom) to fit the width of the PDF (A4=210mm), similar to what the Chrome print to PDF function does.

I am using the following code to generate the PDF ("print" is the id of the `div` I want to write to the PDF):

```
        var {jsPDF} = window.jspdf;
        var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');

        doc.html(window.document.getElementById("print"), {
            html2canvas: {
                //width: 210 //NOT WORKS
            },
            callback: function(doc) {
                doc.save('Generated.pdf');
            }
        });
```

But the div text content is not fitted to the width of the PDF (the text of the div is cut outside the PDF page). What is the right way to do achieve my purpose? I tried so far the following without success:

1. Pass to `html2canvas` options the parameter `width: 210`
2. Define the width of the "print" `div` to `style="width: 210mm;"`

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I already tried jspdf-html2canvas package. The problem with that approach is that it generates an image of the webpage (like an screenshot), therefore is not valid as the quality is not enough.